# Android : communication between activity and object class callback

Tags: android, bluetooth

I'm trying to have an application that lists every bluetooth device around me and can connect more than one at the same time. I have my main activity  that handles an `ArrayList` of my own sensor device class. My sensor class has some property like MAC address, name of device and `BluetoothGattCallback` to manage connection, and communication.

Is there a way to call some functions on my main activity when a `BluetoothGattCallback` is triggered ?

Generally, and as I can see on the web, `BluetoothGattCallback` are integrated into the activity who deals with bluetooth device. For my project I need to manage multiple devices and I choose to make my own class to be able to know which device the callback belongs to.

Maybe I am doing wrong and there is a more simple way.